# Hspace in new commands

Tags: spacing

In the attached code I would like to include the spacing above and below in the definition of the new command, without using *hspace*. Is this possible?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
    \newcommand\Tom {\noindent\hbox to35mm{Tom\hfil}\hangindent=35mm \hangafter=1 }
    \newcommand\Mary {\noindent\hbox to35mm{Mary\hfil}\hangindent=35mm \hangafter=1 }
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \Tom
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    
    \hspace{10mm}
    
    \Mary
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using low level tex primitives here rather than a latex list?

Comment: I would like to build a play script template using the standard Latex commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny: `\hspace` actually introduces *horizontal* space. Because of its definition and of the behaviour of the TeX primitive `\hskip` in vertical mode it looks like it's introducing vertical space.

Add the vertical space in your macros. Note that `\hangafter=1` wasn't actually doing anything.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\Tom{\par\bigskip\noindent\hbox to35mm{Tom\hfil}\hangindent=35mm }
\newcommand\Mary{\par\bigskip\noindent\hbox to35mm{Mary\hfil}\hangindent=35mm }
    
\begin{document}

\Tom
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is
simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

\Mary
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I confused horizontal with vertical. Sorry.